# Load records based on the date using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, ajax

I have a calendar to select a date, this means after selecting a specific date all the staff employed at that date should appear in a table. this is what i have done:

> ```
>    public List<Staff> GetStaff(DateTime arriva)
>     {
>         List<Staff> Staff= new List<Staff>();
>         SqlConnection connection = new ...;
>         SqlCommand query= new SqlCommand("SELECT * From table1 WHERE arriva=@arriva");
>         query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arriva", arriva);
>         connection .Open();
>         SqlDataReader dt= query.ExecuteReader();
>         while (dt.Read())
>         {
>             Staff s= new Staff();
>             s.StaffID= reader["ID"].ToString();
>             s.fname= reader["gname"].ToString();
>             s.sname= reader["sname"].ToString();
>             s.date= Convert.ToDateTime(reader["date"].ToString()).ToString();
>             Staff.Add(s);
>         }
>         connection .Close();
>         return Staff;
>     }
> ```
>
> this is my webmethod

```
        [WebMethod]
    public IEnumerable<Staff> GetStaff(DateTime date)
    {
        List<Staff> s= util.GetStaff(date);
        return s;
    }

        var ajReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        designtable();
        var currentDate = $('#input-group-addon').datepicker('getDate');
        getStaff(currentDate);
    });
```

> this is my table i removed some data to make it simple
>   `function designtable(data) {
>               var tab= 'FnameSnamedate';

```
            table+= '<td>' + msg[student].Fname+ '</td>'; //I am getting Fname from Model e.g. {set;}{get;}
```

.........
            }
            $('#display').html(table);
        }`

> this is my ajax

```
        function getStaff(date) {
        ajReq.abort();
        ajReq = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "folder/filename.asmx/GetStaff",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            date: { date: date },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                BuildTable(msg.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

> this is how i constructed my calender

```
    <div class="input-group bfh-datepicker bfh-datepicker-toggle" data-toggle="bfh-datepicker">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
    <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" style="width: 400px !important; height: 40px;" placeholder="Calendar" />
</div>
```

> this is the calendar i am using [Click here](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/datepicker/#jquery-plugins) its not selecting the date. And these are the library i am using [Library JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLMJH/)

Comment: code for BuildTable() please?

Comment: not sending any data in ajax request. ALso calling `getStaff()` with no date param. `arriva` will be undefined

Comment: when i call getstaff(date) it says date undefined. How do i pass date from the datepicker to getstaff(data)?

Comment: any luck sorting this out?

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX don't send any data to the server, so your GetStaff function isn't receiving it's expected date parameter.

You should pass it with the call or as a parameter or the url (if you manage url routing)

Comment: but in my url i do have `url: "folder/filename.asmx/GetStaff",` this so it should get data from asmx that gets select statement from other file.

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX post will not automatically pass along any parameters to the `WebMethod` that you are calling. You need to include this in the `data` setting. You should consider adding an `id` to your textbox (I'll assume you add one called "tbDate") and then you can get the currently selected date from the datepicker via [Datepicker getDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate):

```
var currentDate = $("#tbDate").datepicker("getDate");
```

Then add that to the `data` setting of the post:

```
data: { data: currentDate }
```

For a total of:

```
var ajReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        designtable();
        var currentDate = $("#input-group-addon").datepicker("getDate");
        getStaff(currentDate);
});

function getStaff(date) {
    ajReq.abort();
    ajReq = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "folder/filename.asmx/GetStaff",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { date: date},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            BuildTable(msg.d);
        }
    });
}
```

[Update with Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ww966/)

Comment: I have tried but i am not getting an error. I have updated my code if that helps. this is how i declared my date: `var currentDate = $("#input-group-addon").datepicker("getDate");`. This is how i declared currentdate: 'data: { date: currentDate}, and this is a error i am getting when running a program:'  0x8000ffff - JavaScript runtime error: Argument not optional

Comment: The block of code that begins with `var ajReq = new XMLHttpRequest();` - in there you are calling both `designtable()` and `getStaff()` without the parameters that are in the constructor.

Comment: You really should edit your question to show any updated code that you have. There was no mention of any function called `getLateStudentsByDate()` so I'm really working in the dark here.

Comment: Sorry, the code should be: yes i am, this is what i have done: var ajReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); $(document).ready(function (){BuildTable();getStaff();});

Comment: Right...you're calling `getStaff();` without any parameters but the constructor is `function getStaff(date)` which is expecting a parameter passed in. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I am getting same error, "Argument not optional", problem might be when you used datepicker. I am using calendar so i am not sure if it has to be datepicker. if i keep getStaff() then i get no error after adding getStaff(currentDate) i get that error?

Comment: I'll mention this again, you **really** should consider updating your question with your current code (not commenting here with a sliver of code) so that people stand a chance at helping you solve the problem.

Comment: i think i know the reason why its not working, i am using bootstrap library and datePicker is not part of that: but the website dose not show how can i select method: this is the calendar i am using (http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/datepicker/#jquery-plugins)

Comment: @BigData I've updated my answer with a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ww966/)